# How to make Websocket thread safe in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket, java-websocket

For what I learned online, WebSocket isn't thread-safe. If so, should it be thread-safe to make communication free from interference when one party is talking with two or more parties separately at the same time? How to make it thread-safe for the ["Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) in a Spring Boot app?